# Style just the parent

Tags: css

I have an element like that

```
<h4><a href="#">Something</a></h4>
<h4>Something else</h4>
```

And I'd like to style the parental h4-element. Is that possible?
So I am looking for somtehhing like

```
h4~ h4>a{
// I don't know the correct operator instead of "~"
border-bottom:10px solid blue;
}
h4{
border-bottom.5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, this can not be done.  You'll need to use another method to indicate which `h4` should be styled as CSS does not support backward or upward traversal of the DOM tree.

Comment: In this particular case, you can style the <a> itself, since it's the only element in the <h4>...